# Расчет коллизий при CRC32

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование, hashcode, crc

Возник вопрос - если существует значение функции `CRC32`, например - `a50985e0` которое было получено из массива байт - `Hello` (т.е. из строки ТОЛЬКО символов.) то какова вероятность что точно такое же значение (`a50985e0`) появится при обработке функцией массива байт полученных из `12345` т.е. из числа ?

Upd.

Исходя из ответов уважаемых @Alex и @Harry делаю вывод что коллизий не избежать в принципе. И при постаточно большем диапазоне числового массива (от 0 до 1 000 000 000) всегда найдется хеш, который совпадет с хешем полученным из строки символов. В связи с этим переформулирую вопрос - существует ли закономерность (возможно ли ее вообще обнаружить) в колличестве этих самых коллизий ? Например хеш `X` из числа `Y` (например 12345) проверен в обшем массиве хешей (0 - 2 000 000 000) и найдено 10 коллизий, и так же для любого числа - врезультируещем массиве существует хотябы 10 коллизий. В то время как хеш из символьной строки `Hello` даст всего 1 коллизию и так же любая другая строка из символов даст не более 1 коллизии. Существует ли подобная законормерность ?

Comment: Поскольку CRC32 имеет размер ровно 32 бита :), то всего может принимать 2^32 значений. Если принять гипотезу, что все значения распределены равномерно (идеальный случай), то теоретически вероятность коллизии - 2^-32.

Но! вы намерены получать значения только из чисел. Какого их количества? Например, если вы спрашиваете вероятность совпадения CRC32 для `Hello` и `12345`, то понятно - нуль. Если для *всех возможных строк из цифр произвольной длины* - то около 2^-32. Уточните условие, а? А то при невнятном ТЗ результат... ну, сами знаете.

Comment: @Harry если говорить совсем просто, то можно ли понять чем был хеш изначально - набором чисел или набором букв. Если имеется хеши 2 млрд массивов байт от 0 до 2000000000. Какова вероятность среди этих 2млд встретить ещё один хеш, сформированный из другого, не числового массива.

Comment: Точно вероятность не оценю, но - ненулевая. Например, CRC32 (версии IEEE) совпадает для строки `Windows` и строки `1390518529`. Поэтому гарантированно - точно не получится. Думаю, что все же гипотеза о равномерном распределении значений crc32 вполне приемлема.

Comment: Если CRC32 вычисляете вы - вычисляйте модифицированный CRC32, скажем, устанавливая определенный бит, если использованы только цифры, и сбрасывая - если нет :) Тогда все будет как вы хотиет...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вначале хочу заметить, если вы задаетесь таким вопросом, то скорее всего вы используйте функцию чек-суммы не по прямому назначению. А значит, вы делаете что-то неправильно.

Насколько я понял, вам интересно, одинаков ли шанс получить коллизию, если на входе строка из букв, или строка из цифр. Хочу заметить, что если у вас откуда-то приходят случайные строки длиной 5 символов (для примера), то шанс что у вас появятся одинаковые строки из цифр на много-много порядков выше, чем когда приходят строки из букв.

Что бы показать, что шансы получить коллизию одинаковы, я сгенерировал 100 млн чек-сумм для строк длиной 20 (я взял 20, что бы не создавались одинаковые строки из чисел), и посчитал коллизии внутри строк из чисел, внутри строк из букв, и взаимные коллизии между строками из чисел и букв. Вот мой код на C#:

```
private static uint crc32(byte[] data)
{
    uint crc = 0xffffffff;
    uint poly = 0xedb88320;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        uint c = (crc ^ data[i]) & 0xff;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            c = (c & 1) != 0 ? poly ^ (c >> 1) : c >> 1;
        crc = c ^ (crc >> 8);
    }
    return crc ^ 0xffffffff;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[][] digits = new byte[0x10000][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        digits[i] = new byte[0x10000];

    byte[][] chars = new byte[0x10000][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        chars[i] = new byte[0x10000];

    var rnd = new Random(123);
    int iterations = 100000000;

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678901234567890");
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(20);
        buffer[index]++;
        if (buffer[index] > '9')
            buffer[index] = (byte)'0';

        uint crc = crc32(buffer);
        digits[crc >> 16][crc & 0xFFFF]++;
    }

    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefwxyzabcdefwxyz");
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(20);
        buffer[index]++;
        if (buffer[index] > 'z')
            buffer[index] = (byte)'a';

        uint crc = crc32(buffer);
        chars[crc >> 16][crc & 0xFFFF]++;
    }

    int digitsCollisions = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 0x10000; j++)
            if (digits[i][j] > 1)
                digitsCollisions += digits[i][j];

    int charsCollisions = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 0x10000; j++)
            if (chars[i][j] > 1)
                charsCollisions += chars[i][j];

    int digitsCharsCollisions = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 0x10000; j++)
            if (chars[i][j] > 0 && digits[i][j] > 0)
                digitsCharsCollisions += chars[i][j] * digits[i][j];

    Console.WriteLine(digitsCollisions);
    Console.WriteLine(charsCollisions);
    Console.WriteLine(digitsCharsCollisions);
}
```

Результат:

```
2298490
2304243
2330855
```

Как видно, вероятность получить коллизию одинаковая.

В другом тесте я брал длину входных данных 10 байт, и вместо случайных чисел просто брал строковое представление числа `i`. Результат получился другой:

```
4431872
2301156
2324554
```

Как видно, коллизий на числах в 2 раза больше, хотя чек-сумма считалась на уникальных входных данных. Это происходит потому, что в случайной строке из букв длиной 10 байт больше энтропии, чем в строке чисел. CRC-32 не является полноценной криптографической хеш-фукнцией, и в ней нет лавинного эффекта. С хорошей хеш-функцией мы бы получили одинаковый результат.

Comment: Читатели SO, обратите внимание, это хороший ответ (жаль, правила позволяют отметить лишь одним плюсом)

Comment: Отличный ответ. Только получается что : 1111 и строка `"1111"` дают разные чек суммы?

Comment: Сколько по времени заняла генерация 100млн значений?

Comment: @Сергей CRC-32 принимает на вход байты. Строку можно посимвольно преобразовать в байты. Число 1111 можно представить в виде 2 байт. Результат будет разный. 100млн генерировалось где-то 1-2 минуты. Код неоптимизированный, можно и быстрее.

Comment: Наверное у вас отличный ПК. На моём ушло ~30 минут.  Не могли бы вы проделать этот тест ещё раз что бы сравнить число коллизий в строковом представлении чисел, т.е. именно "12345678" а не 12345678. Будет ли в данном случае число коллизий так сильно отличается.

Comment: @Сергей мой код выше работает со строковым представлением чисел. Во втором тесте так же было

Comment: @Zergatul выходит что если изначально имелось число, разобранное на массив байт, то CRC32 даст меньше коллизий, полученных хешей чем строка ? Играет ли роль в данном случае полином ? ведь полином это именно то на что делится массив что бы получить остаток (если я правильно понял).

Comment: @Сергей Да, самый лучший вариант это разбить число на байты. В таком случае вероятность коллизии минимальная, потому что полноценно используется каждый бит. Сложно сказать, влияет ли полином. Я думаю, что нет. Там не совсем привычное деление. Там деление над полем GF(2). В него совсем другие свойства.

Comment: @Zergatul вообще полином же может быть любым ?

Comment: @Сергей Я не знаю, там сложная математическая теория под этим всем.

Answer (score 2):

Если хэш-функция "хорошая", то понять от чего она возникла (цифры, или буквы) нельзя. Но! [CRC32 дает повтор с вероятностью более 50% (сюрприз!) уже на 80 тысячах входных строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Да, но это же типичный парадокс дней рождений :) - а человека интересует, не окажется ли, что все цифры рождены весной и летом, а буквы - зимой и осенью :)

Answer (score 2):

Сообразил. В вашей постановке задачи - вероятность 1.
Всегда найдется такая последовательность **не из цифр**, которая даст вам то же значение crc32.

Если постановка задачи - с какой вероятностью существует строка не из цифр, совпадающая по crc32 с одним из данных значений.

Comment: хотя бы одна коллизия будет всегда?

Comment: И понять чем был хеш crc изначально не возможно?

Comment: Понимаете, откуда вы берете строки? Если это из таблицы логарифмов какой-нибудь - то вряд ли вам попадется строка с буквами. Если из книги - дело другое. У вас же нет никаких данных о том, что такое ваши crc, откуда данные. Ну поймите же, вероятность того, что вы встретите подряд 100 мужчин, капитально зависит от того, где вы находитесь - в обычном городе, женском монастыре или военной части! Вы же ничего не говорите о том, откуда данные. Просто - сказать 100% по crc32, что было исходно - невозможно принципиально.

Comment: У вас сама постановка все же в корне неверна... Что-то мне кажется, что это - [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)...

Comment: развернул вопрос. надеюсь теперь он стал понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется ответ на ваш вопрос в этом утверждении

> Для любого CRC32 хеша всегда существует единственная последовательность из четырех байт, хеш которых даст заданный

(данное утверждение следует из того, что все 256 значений полинома имеют различный старший байт)

Исходя из этого утверждения, коллизий у вас будет столько, сколько четверок байт в сообщении максимальной длины